# COMPLETAR INPUT CON TKINTER

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

tengo un pequeño problema con tkinter, he dejado un apartado para escribir para realizar un formulario, 
`input("CUÁNTOS AÑOS TIENE?")`
`input("ERES HOMBRE O MUJER?")`
y cuando meto los datos y le doy al enter simplemente escribe en consola lo que escribí anteriormente pero no se "ejecuta" y no me deja seguir, si pueden ayudarme sería de muchisima ayuda.

```
def myClick():
    print (ventana.get())
```

Comment: Hola Michael, ¿qué quieres decir con no se ejecuta exactamente? Aparentemente tienes una callback asociada a un `Entry` supongo que simplemente imprime en stdout mediante `print` su contenido... Considera dar algo de más contexto a a pregunta, ¿qué debería pasar cuando el evento tiene lugar exactamente? Agregar algo más de código con más contexto o al menos un [mcve] sería de ayuda.

Comment: Me refiero que si quiero ejecutar por ejemplo una calculadora, y me pregunta input("dime el valor del numero 1"), como hago para introducirle el número a través de tkinter? Ya que ahora mismo solo lo imprime en pantalla

Comment: Si usa una GUI olvidate de `input()`, usa un widget como `tkinter.Entry` para las entradas de usuario, o botones o cualquier otro widget dependiendo de que quieras hacer. Podrías emular una terminal en Tkinter, pero entonces no tiene mucho sentido la GUI. Una vez que el usuario ingrese algo en el Entry o lo que sea asocia la callback a Enter o usa un botón   "Calcular" o lo que sea y en la función asociada al evento haces el cálculo y lo muestras en otro widget, como un Label.

Comment: ¿Lo que pretendes conseguir es que el dato ingresado por la ventana se muestre en la terminal?

Comment: Lo que pretendíe era que algo que pusiese en tkinter, como que contestase a un input

Answer (score 1):

Si no he entendido mal, lo que pretendes conseguir es que el dato ingresado por la ventana se muestre en la terminal de ejecución. De ser así, puedes hacer uso de la instrucción propia de `tkinter` `Entry()` con el widget d `tkinter.Entry` para dichas entradas de usuario

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


def ventanaCapturaDatos():

    def devolverDatos():
        textoCaja = entryTexto.get()
        texto.set(textoCaja)
        root.destroy()


    root = Tk()
    root.title("Ventana para la edad de una persona")

    # FRAME DE ENTRADA DE DATOS

    miFrame = Frame(root)
    miFrame.pack()

    texto = StringVar()


    # ENTRY 

    entryTexto = Entry(miFrame, justify = CENTER, textvariable = texto)
    entryTexto.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    root.iconbitmap()         # Puedes poner un 'logo' personalizado si lo deseas
    root.geometry('350x200')

    # BOTÓN ACEPTAR

    botonAceptar = Button(miFrame, text = "Aceptar", command = lambda:devolverDatos())
    botonAceptar.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "e", padx = 5, pady = 5)

    root.mainloop()

    return texto.get()


print("Edades de una persona")

texto = ventanaCapturaDatos()

print("¿Cuántos años tienes?")
print(texto)
```

Comment: No es que se muestre en la terminal, sino que pretendo asignar los valores añadidos a unas variables, como que i = input(), y desde tkinter darle valor

Answer (score 0):

después de haber introducido un valor numérico por ejemplo 50 en la ventana creada con el Entry, como se puede ejecutar ese número en el terminal? Es decir, se le ha asignado un botón que cuando le das, hace print en el terminal, pero como es posible que dicho numero en ve de imprimirse, se ejecute en el terminal si por ejemplo está esperando una respuesta numérica para poder seguir ejecutandose?
Gracias